# unable to compile payable(this).transfer(msg.value);

Tags: solidity, remix

playing aroung with payable following a course tutorial, it's working fine for the instructor but me for me it's throwing away an error. I'm trying to execute a function to send ether to the actual deployed contract.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should first convert to address and then to payable

```
payable(address(this)).transfer(msg.value);
```

also this code doesn't have much sense since you are transferring to the contract the same ether amount the contract is already receiving, you can just leave the function in blank if you only want to receive the ether or use some receive function

Comment: Thank you for your help, now I got it. In fact I'm not trying to make a deposit function or receive, I want to transfer ether, but you're right it's not executing. Isn't 'this' refer to the deployed contract, and 'msg.value' to the contract executing the function? I would like to try to send ether from the deployed contract to the contract executing the function. Is it doable?

Comment: if by from the deployed contract you mean that contract and by executing contract the contract who call that function you can do something like this `payable(msg.sender).call{value: amountInEther}("")`, remember that msg.value is the amount of ether the contract is receiving in that call